# How to fix the following output plot by R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using the following dataset. Now when I plot this as shown in the ggplot command, the x-axis divides the year values as 2000,2002.5,2005,2007.5 and so on instead of 2001,2002,2003,2004, and so on. What can be done to fix this?

```
d1<-structure(list(year = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2001", "2002", 
"2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
"2011", "2012"), class = "factor"), val1 = c(42244L, 43161L, 
42444L, 43579L, 43424L, 45116L, 48003L, 48835L, 47856L, 50024L
), val2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L), val3 = c(109467L, 
112956L, 110623L, 125657L, 127560L, 137180L, 156412L, 164861L, 
174395L, 180413L), val4 = c(20381L, 18346L, 16636L, 18119L, 17173L, 
19234L, 22113L, 22624L, 23374L, 23280L), val5 = c(7056L, 6679L, 
6287L, 6261L, 7197L, 7581L, 10321L, 10535L, 10242L, 12080L), 
    val6 = c(12823L, 12056L, 11101L, 11428L, 12665L, 11783L, 
    9861L, 8250L, 7802L, 6775L), val7 = c(220L, 101L, 55L, 68L, 
    212L, 85L, 95L, 125L, 49L, 81L), val8 = c(694L, 2527L, 1066L, 
    1700L, 2976L, 1665L, 1229L, 1086L, 879L, 958L), val9 = c(12439L, 
    12698L, 15351L, 12771L, 13192L, 12420L, 13753L, 14943L, 14368L, 
    10404L), val10 = c(17819L, 18221L, 15643L, 19250L, 19326L, 
    20967L, 23658L, 27208L, 30526L, 34250L), val11 = c(20446L, 
    21236L, 19994L, 22489L, 23212L, 23792L, 25363L, 25036L, 25845L, 
    27074L), val12 = c(243589L, 247981L, 239200L, 261322L, 266955L, 
    279823L, 310808L, 323510L, 335336L, 345339L)), .Names = c("year", 
"val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6", "val7", "val8", 
"val9", "val10", "val11", "val12"), 
row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and then I run

```
d2<-(d1[,c(1,2)]) #(here d1 is the main (csv)file)
ggplot(d2,aes(x=year,y=val1))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't replicate this behaviour. The `x` axis is showing what you want. Maybe you have an old `ggplot2` version. Your `geom_line()` isn't working though, try `ggplot(d2,aes(x=year,y=val1, group = 1))+geom_line()+geom_point()`

Comment: The behaviour you describe happens when the x values are numeric. Then you should write ggplot(d2,aes(x=as.factor(year),y=val1))+geom_line()+geom_point(). Your x-values are already a factor.

Comment: @Ido Tamir When used as.factor, then line plot is not implemented, only the points are plotted.

Comment: @David Arenburg adding group=1 to the command, still results same

Comment: I used your data and everything worked fine. What is the version of your `ggplot`?

Comment: ggplot version 1.0.0